# To find the limit of given sequence.

Tags: limits

What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{n\ge2}\Biggl(1-\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\Biggr)^{2}$ ?Not getting any start to try.Any hint?

Comment: Your notation does not make much sense, unless you really want to compute the limit of a constant. Additionally, what have you attempted?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$1-\dfrac2{n(n+1)}=\dfrac{n-1}n\cdot\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}=\dfrac{f(n)}{f(n+2)}$$ where $f(m)=\dfrac{m-1}m$

Comment: $\frac{1}{9}$?.